# using php variable in javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, html

My problem is I have a php variable $ba with a value of 147 retrieved from a DB the below snipets of my code does not work, no image is shown. If I add $ba=147; before the fill_div call it works perfectly. I am stumped as to why it dos'nt work when $ba populated from the DB. 
In both cases a check of the source code for the page shows the call being filled correctly fill_div("147");

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function fill_div(ba)
    {
        document.getElementById("ba").innerHTML="<img src='admin/images/image.gif'/>"; 
    }
</script>

<script>   
    fill_div("<? echo stripslashes($ba); ?>"); 
</script

<div id="<? echo $ba ?>" style="border:1px solid; width:120px; height:40px"></div>
```

Comment: If it's not populated from DB - how this question is related to HTML and javascript?

Comment: Please show the code where `$ba` is being declared. Is it inside of a function?  Also, your javascript should be `document.getElementById(ba);`

Comment: removed quotes from getElementById(ba) did'nt make any differance

Comment: @user1664457 what's the actual value of `$ba` when it fails

Comment: if $ba has a value of 127 and is set from a mysql_query it fails if I manualy set the value to 127 using $ba=127; or $ba="127"; right before the fill_div() call it works

Answer (score 4):

You're passing the string literal`"ba"` to `getElementById` when you need to pass the variable `ba`

```
document.getElementById(ba).innerHTML="<img src='admin/images/image.gif'/>";
```

Also the stripslashes might not be a good idea if `$ba` has quotes in it, if `$ba` has a `"` in it will cause an error in your JavaScript if it is not escaped.

Comment: I added stripslashes on the off chance it may make a difference and the " have now been removed with same results

Answer (score 3):

try ..

```
 document.getElementById(ba).innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("ba")
```

should be

```
document.getElementById(ba)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your document.getElementById to:

document.getElementById(ba)

If it has quotes (as in your example code) "ba" is treated as a string, not a variable.

Comment: thanks for your answer but even without the " still not working